# Sencha Touch radio buttons

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to find an example of how to setup some simple radio buttons in Sencha Touch. Can anyone point me at a good example?

Answer (score 2):

you can try ..

```
this.viewOne = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    text: 'Form',
    iconCls: 'bookmarks',
    items: [
      {
        xtype:'radiofield,
        name: 'radiogroup',
        value: 'A',
        label: 'radio1'
      },{
        xtype:'radiofield,
        name: 'radiogroup',
        value: 'B',
        label: 'radio2'
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The kitchensink demo has a Radio example on the User Experience -> Form example.  It's the "Favorite color" of the form.  Also, Radio extends Checkbox, so if you can find examples of Checkbox it's similar.

[Radio documentation here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.form.Radio)

The main thing is to give each Radio in a group the same name like the following :

```
this.viewOne = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    text: 'Form',
    iconCls: 'bookmarks',
    items: [
      new Ext.form.Radio({
        name: 'radiogroup',
        value: 'A',
        label: 'radio1'
      }), new Ext.form.Radio({
        name: 'radiogroup',
        value: 'B',
        label: 'radio2'
      })
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Having problems posting the HTML ...i essentially wrapped the above code in the hello world example. The hello world example worked ok but when i pasted the FormPanel code in i see nothing at all.

Comment: I don't know which Hello world example you're doing, so i don't know what you pasted where, you can edit your question to add the HTML you've got.